# Insert data into a remote mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, android

We have an android app that currently sends data to a php script which writes to a mysql DB on the same server. We are thinking of using a scalable remote DB e.g. amazon RDS.

The question is how does our android app write to these remote DBs? Do they have some kind of rest API, or do we have to send the data to the same php script on our server but use that to post to the remote mysql DB?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on the remote database.  Sift through their developer docs to find out what you need to do to work with them.

You can most likely do either option you mentioned (interact directly through your Android app or use a PHP script on your server as a man-in-the-middle).

Personally, I would go for a man-in-the-middle PHP script on your server that acts as an API, because it allows you to change remote DBs without changing/repackaging your Android app.

Comment: The middle man php script would allow us to change the remote db on demand, but if we go this route are we really offloading much work from our server?  If our server still has to handle the incoming data is that saving much load compared to just writing it straight to a local mysql DB?  I guess the answer depends on if the mysql is the bottleneck of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps either should be able to do the database insert; we do not know at the moment.  You will need to determine if the middle tier is necesssary or if you will do all your processing on the device.  For example, you may wish to use the middle PHP piece because it is easy to change, as opposed to the device.  If everything were always the same, not matter what, you could send out directorly from the device given a secure link and give it is capable to do so in the first place.

Since the future is hard to see, I'd stick with the PHP.  This is based on the limited information you give here.